# Where to inspect the database that I've created using my emulator

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, pouchdb

I'm recently creating a react-native app working with PouchDB, but I don't really know where to inspect the db that I've created.

I've searched on internet most of them is using the web browser, but I really don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

**IndexedDB/WebSQL inspectors**

You can use the normal developer tools to see what your database looks like under the hood.

In Chrome, just choose Overflow icon ☰ → Tools → Developer Tools. Then click the Resources tab, then IndexedDB, and you should see the following:

This is the raw IndexedDB representation of your PouchDB, so it is very fine-grained. However, you may find it useful.

[image]

In Safari, your database will be under Develop → Show Web Inspector → Resources → Databases.

[image]

Click [this link](https://pouchdb.com/guides/) to learn more about pouchDB.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm still little confuse is it like once I created an db in my emulator then it will automatically appear in the dev tools? or? cause I'm really confuse. I know that if I use it in the web app it will work but I don't really understand how the db will display in the chrome while I was doing the app.